# How to click a link which is created javascript with Goutte

Tags: goutte

Does anyone know how can I click a link which is set by javascript with Goutte ?

For example the link is like this.

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('Detail').click()" href="#a" id="Link01" name="Link01">get detail</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You know Goutte cannot explain javascript. Selenium or casperjs is a better choice.